# Can I use browserify to transpile into a NPM module that can be imported into another project?

Tags: node.js, browserify

Is it possible for me to use browserify to transpile my ES6 code into one distribution published to NPM?

Here is what I'm doing. I am trying to create a NPM module that will be used in many of my projects. The NPM module I have is something derived from an already existing project using grunt-browserify+babelify. The problem I'm running into is when I import the NPM module into another project and run browserify on it, I'm getting an

```
>> Error: Cannot find module './foo/bar' from '/Users/joeuser/working/project123/node_modules/my-npm-module/lib'
```

Is what I'm trying even possible?

Comment: It is very much possible. I don't know how you're setting it up, but on first glance you're importing `./foo` (notice `./`, a relative path). Try dropping the `./`. If that import is _inside_ your module, you may have missed adding `files` to `package.json`